# Convert a dateString from a browser to java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date, browser, java.util.date

I am facing an issue with parsing/converting a dateString from browser to Date format in Java.
The following are some of the values that I got from the browser.

```
dateStr = "01-01-2010 05:06:22";
dateStr = "Mon Oct 11 07:00:00 EDT 2010";
dateStr = "Fri May 25 2012 08:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)";
```

Each dateStr is in different format and at the back-end I was using a SimpleDateFormat with a particular format to convert dateStr. Since the input dateStr format is not consistent, any idea about how this can be handled in the backend?

There is little access to the frontend code/folks.

PS: I did google about this and read the related topics here on StackOverflow.

Any sort of help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How do you receive that date string on your back-end? It might have been parsed already and be waiting for you behind a method call.

Comment: There needs to be some consistency for this to work. You may need more than one SimpleDateFormat objects and test all of them for a result, or at least until you can find one that parses your String.

Comment: @PhilippReichart The dateStr variables hold the exact values that I have posted.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah, I thought of that where I could use 3 different SimpleDateFormat statements, but hoping of a cleaner way to handle any other pattern as well.

Comment: @codezilla: I know of no black magic that will allow you to handle "any other pattern", and can't imagine how this could exist.

Comment: one thing to be aware of is SimpleDateFormat isn't thread safe, and can return weird/junk values in multithreaded situations. Use a thread local if you need thread safe code that uses SimpleDateFormat

Comment: You can use `SimpleDateFormat` class for the string formatting to Date object. You can take reference from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: please re-read the question. The original poster is already familiar with use of SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Then what is the problem ?????????

Comment: @Bhavik: He wants to convert several different date Strings that are all different in their structure. The solution is as given in my comment and in Tomasz' answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels will the below code work ? I have doubt

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes Sir, I kind of did not sound right in my previous comment. I am basing my approach on your comment and Tomasz's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have all the pieces you need. First define patterns for every possible date format you can get from the client. Then simply iterate over these formats and try parsing input using each of them and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Continue looping if `SimpleDateFormat` returns `null` (parse error) until you get valid `Date`. You might ask: what to do if input matches more then one pattern (is `02-01-2012` 2nd of January or February the 1st?) Well, then you have bigger issues...

Comment: I will start with the idea you have mentioned, so that I have something to improve upon. Thank you !